# Logically, is there a reason why ++i++ can not be a valid expression?

Tags: c++, c, syntax, language-features, gcc

I had to increment my integer twice in a loop, so I thought I would try and be clever:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; !sl.isEmpty(); ++i++) { ... }
```

`++i++` however is not an assignable expression, at least in GCC. 
Is there a technical reason why this is the case, that logically, it would be impossible to implement such a syntax rule?

In my mind,

```
int i(0);
QTextStream(stdout) << i++; // 0
QTextStream(stdout) << ++i; // 2
i = 0;
QTextStream(stdout) << ++i++; // impossible, but it should give 1
```

However I assume that there are good reasons why maybe this can not be the case.
Just curious.

Comment: Highly related (if not a dupe): https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16135/what-makes-c-developers-so-curious-if-i-i

Comment: Direct link to answer: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/79729/

Comment: "*impossible, but it should give 1*" Um... why?

Comment: @NicolBolas hypothetically, because `++i` would evaluate before being sent.

Comment: `++i++` is an error by the current definition of C.  The language could easily be changed to have an explicit rule for this expression (produce the value `((i+=2),i-1)`), but given how often it would be used, it's hardly worth the effort.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are misinterpreting GCC's error message:

```
<source>:5:8: error: lvalue required as increment operand

     ++i++;

        ^
```

Note where the error message is pointing: the postfix++ part.

The token sequence `++i++` will, by [C/C++'s operator precedence rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), be interpreted as `++(i++)`. So the postfix++ happens first.

The postfix++ operator does two things. It returns the current value of the operand and it increments the operand... *in that order* (conceptually). This means that, when `i++` returns something, what it returns *is not `i`*. It has no relationship to `i`. It's not a variable; it's just an `int`.

The ++prefix operator is defined to do two things: increment the operand it is given and return the operand... *in that order* (again, conceptually).

Here's the thing though: incrementing an operand requires that the operand is a variable (or a reference in C++). That is, the operand must be a thing that is assignable, that can go on the lefthand side of an assignment. Thus, such a thing is called a "lvalue".

You cannot call either increment operator on something that isn't an lvalue. It simply doesn't make sense. It's about as reasonable as wanting to do `5 += 3`; you cannot change the value of 5. You can compute `5 + 3`, but you're not changing the value of 5 or 3. You are computing a *new value*, which is neither 5 nor 3. Such values cannot appear on the lefthand side of an assignment; they can only appear on the righthand side. Thus, they are called "rvalues".

Postfix++ returns an rvalue. It *must* return an rvalue, because that is the nature of the operation. Remember: by the time postfix++ is done, the lvalue *has been changed*. But the result of the expression is the *previous* value. Therefore, that value must be a new value, divorced from the variable that was used to generate it. There is no variable which holds this value; therefore, what postfix++ generates is an *rvalue*.

And you cannot increment an rvalue expression. This is why `++5` does not work. And `++(i++)` does not work for the same reason.

This is all *necessary* by the nature of what postfix++ means. The only way to change this would be to make postfix++ return an lvalue. But the only lvalue it has is its operand. And by the time an expression that consumes postfix++ sees the resulting lvalue, that variable will have been *changed*.

And that would make postfix++ behave exactly like ++prefix. So there would be no reason to have both.

There's no way around it. If you want postfix++ to actually do what postfix++ does, then `++i++` *must* be nonsensical code.

---

Now, could you redefine the meaning of assignment-like operations, so that you could make `5 += 3` simply become the equivalent of `5 + 3`? That is, assignment to rvalues simply computes a new value (`5 = 3` evaluates to the expression `3`). In theory, yes.

However, if a user writes something like `++(i++)`, you need to ask yourself a question: what did they *intend* to have happen?

If I pretend not to know much about C++, when I see that expression, I would *expect* the value of `i` to be incremented twice, and that the result of the expression will be the current value of `i`. But that's not what would happen under those rules. The `i++` part would return the original value of `i` (which again, is *why* postfix++ exists to begin with). So the ++prefix will increment this value, resulting in `i` only being incremented once. And the result would be the original value incremented once.

Similarly, `5 += 3` becoming `5 + 3` seems weird. That looks like a case of the compiler saying, "What you said doesn't make sense, so I'm going to guess at what you *meant* to say." And that's always a dangerous road to walk.

Comment: Look at [DWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) for the last paragraph.

Comment: There is another way to make `++i++` valid: Change the operator precedence so that it parses as `(++i)++`. To be honest, it would still not pass any code review done by me.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau The parentheses ensure the precedence but do not introduce a sequence before constraint.  According to 6.8.1/10 this is UB, parenthesis or not.

Comment: @Christophe, you have a point there. I was just thinking syntactically.

Answer (score 3):

Although *far* from advisable (at least under normal circumstances), it's certainly possible to use operator overloading to get a compiler to accept an expression like `++i++` in C++ (getting a sane code reviewer to accept it is quite another story).

```
#include <iostream>

class DontDoThis {
    int v;
public:
    DontDoThis(int init) : v(init) {}
    DontDoThis &operator++() { ++v; return *this; }
    DontDoThis &operator++(int) { ++v; return *this; }

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, DontDoThis const &d) { 
        return os << d.v;
    }
};

int main() { 
    DontDoThis v = 2;

    std::cout << ++v++;
}
```

In this case I've overloaded it so pre-increment and post-increment both do exactly the same thing, but you could have them act differently from each other--though there's room for substantial question about what behavior for this expression really makes sense. I tend to agree with @Nicol that this is just a bad idea in general, and we're almost certainly better off without it.